# concatination of cut putting variable inside it

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting, cut

I have coded the following code :

```
Fileformat=$2
Fileresource=$1

 for (( j=1; j<=3; j++ ))
       {


        First_Pos_resource=$(awk -F ';' 'NR=='$j'{print $3}' "${Fileformat}")
        Length_resource=$(awk -F ';' 'NR=='$j'{print $4}' "${Fileformat}")
        last_Pos_resource=$((Pos_resource+Length_resource))
        range=${First_Pos_resource}"-"${last_Pos_resource}
        OUtput_line=${OUtput_line}$(cut -c${range} "${Fileresource}")

       }
            echo $OUtput_line  >> OutputFile.txt
```

Fileformat : is the structure that the outputFile.txt should respect. 
Fileformat.txt defines the: 
Name;Position In Output;Position In resourcefile ; lenght of string to cut from the ressource file

Fileformat.txt looks like this :

```html
first;1;15;2
second;3;6;4
blabla;7;23;8
```

Fileresource :it contains a line of strings,from which we generate the output file

it looks like this :

```
sfdssdffgdfglkjdfsld lkjlkkfdssdfssdf
```

So to sum up : File resource + File Format = OutputFile.txt

Explanation

```
first;1;15;2 + sfdssdffgdfglkjdfsld lkjlkkfdssdfssdf = jd
second;3;6;4 + sfdssdffgdfglkjdfsld lkjlkkfdssdfssdf = ffgd
blabla;7;23;5 + sfdssdffgdfglkjdfsld lkjlkkfdssdfssdf = dfssd
```

so after concatenation I should have this result in the output file : Output.txt looks like this

```
jdffgddfssd
```

I have coded the above lines but I have a problem with the white-space generated after concatenation

output displayed but not desired:

```html
jd ffgd dfssd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message looks like your variables are not being correctly set.  Without access to your precise input files, it's hard to debug this; but copy/pasting your data produces `range` values like this for me:

```
range=15-+2
range=6-+4
range=23-+8
```

which are obviously incorrect.  If you wanted the shell to perform arithmetic on the value, you need to use `((` *arithmetic expressions* `))` for that.

Anyway, your loop looks like it's completely inside out.  Also, refactoring the entire script into a single Awk script will make it both more efficient and simpler.

```
awk -F ';' 'NR==FNR { res = res $0; next }
  { printf "%s", substr(res, $3, $4) }
  END { print "" }' resource fileformat.txt
```

I don't get exactly the output you prescribe but I may have some copy/paste error in the data, or misunderstand how exactly you want to calculate the substring offsets.

(I couldn't help but correct the spelling of "resource".)

Comment: thanks @tripleee I have corrected the code and the post , But I get a whitespace

Comment: I fixed it , OUtput_line=${OUtput_line}$(cut -c${range} "${Fileresource}" '|' awk 'NR==1 {print $1}')

Comment: That's a horrible fix. Just refactor the code to a single Awk script.